# Magento 2: Setting up Three.js and OrbitControls.js

Tags: magento2

I'm working with Magento 2.3 and need to use Three.js for a graphic interface. The interface uses OrbitControls.js, a non-AMD compliant library.

The version of Three I'm using is r89. I have no idea about the version or Orbit Controls.

How do I setup my code so i can use these libraries?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what worked for me: app/design/frontend/[theme_path]/requirejs-config.js

```
define('three', ['js/three/three.min'], function (THREE) {
    window.THREE = THREE;
    return THREE;
});

define('OrbitControls', ['js/three/OrbitControls'], function (OrbitControls) {
    window.OrbitControls = OrbitControls;
    return OrbitControls;
});

var config = {
    paths: {
        three: 'js/three/three.min',
        orbitControls: 'js/three/OrbitControls',
    },
    shim: {
        'js/three/OrbitControls': ['three']
    }
};
```

Then, in my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([
        'jquery',
        'three',
        'OrbitControls'
    ], function ($) {
       // All the stuff that runs when ready ...
       init();
    });

    function init() {
        // Your code.
    }
</script>
```